# Replacing tabs with spaces from nth column to last column

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, whitespace

I have a tab-separated file which looks as follows:

```
GCF_000014165.1_ASM1416v1.dist_nbr_anntn        WP_011558474.1  1155234 1156286 44173   polyketide synthase [Mycobacterium]
GCF_000014165.1_ASM1416v1.dist_nbr_anntn        WP_011558475.1  1156298 1156807 12      isoprenylcysteine       carboxyl        methyltransferase       [Mycobacterium]
GCF_000014165.1_ASM1416v1.dist_nbr_anntn        WP_011558476.1  1156804 1157820 -3      NAD(P)/FAD-dependent    oxidoreductase  [Mycobacterium]
```

How do I replace tabs from column 6 to the last column with spaces?

The output should look as follows:

```
GCF_000014165.1_ASM1416v1.dist_nbr_anntn        WP_011558474.1  1155234 1156286 44173   polyketide synthase [Mycobacterium]
GCF_000014165.1_ASM1416v1.dist_nbr_anntn        WP_011558475.1  1156298 1156807 12      isoprenylcysteine carboxyl methyltransferase [Mycobacterium]
GCF_000014165.1_ASM1416v1.dist_nbr_anntn        WP_011558476.1  1156804 1157820 -3      NAD(P)/FAD-dependent oxidoreductase [Mycobacterium]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU sed, it's as simple as:

```
sed 's/\t/ /6g' file
```

> The s command can be followed by zero or more of the following flags:
>
> ```
> g
> ```
>
> Apply the replacement to all matches to the regexp, not just the
>   first.
>
> ```
> number
> ```
>
> Only replace the numberth match of the regexp.
>
> interaction in s command Note: the POSIX standard does not specify
>   what should happen when you mix the g and number modifiers, and
>   currently there is no widely agreed upon meaning across sed
>   implementations. For GNU sed, the interaction is defined to be: ignore
>   matches before the numberth, and then match and replace all matches
>   from the numberth on.

See [sed, a stream editor: The `s` Command](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command)